# Copy cell range between workbooks from same folder

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have:

```
Sub Ranger()
Dim rng As Range
Dim WB1 As Workbook, WB2 As Workbook, ActiveWB As Workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
Dim FName As String

FName = "General Text"
Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook
Set WS1 = WB1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FName)
Set WS2 = WB2.Sheets(1)

With WS2
    Set rng = .Range(Range("A1"), Range("A5"))
    End With

With WS1
    rng.Copy .Cells(1, 1)
    End With

WB2.Close
End Sub
```

Which aims to copy the range A1:A5 in the newly opened workbook into the original workbook (ThisWorkbook). It currently opens the second workbook but does not copy anything into the first workbook. There are also no errors and I would like to avoid using specific names in setting WB1/WB2 as WB2 could be either .xls or .xlsx

Comment: Way overcomplicated, but should work... Try simply making the ranges equal instead of .Copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for me:

```
Sub Ranger()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim WB2 As Workbook
  Dim FName As String

  FName = "D:\Tuchanka\Temp\pelda.xlsx"
  Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FName)

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A5").Value = WB2.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A5").Value

  WB2.Close
End Sub
```

Using variables and with statements is pointless in your situation, as instead of making your code simpler and easier to read, they just add a lot of gibberish and make your code seem way too complex. Only use these if you need them.

Comment: I need to copy values from WB2 into WB1. Your code opens WB2 but doesn't copy anything into WB1

Comment: Yes it does, I have tested it. Something else is wrong then. Maybe your workbook opens in protected mode? Can you manually copy the data? Have you tried stepping through the code? Is the target workbook writeable?

Comment: Apologies - your code works! It's just that I had another workbook open so it was defining that one as ThisWorkbook whilst I was scratching my head and looking at another workbook